# Javascript Date.getDay() returns wrong day ( `Date(2022,5,3)).getDay() == 5` )

Tags: javascript, date

Note: This might be a duplicate, but is more concise than other questions posted.

`(new Date(2022,5,3)).getDay()` returns `5`. Expected is `3`.

What is going on?

Comment: Yes. And I wonder why that question didn't show up neither in search results, nor during question creation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer

use `getDate()` ([Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp))

#### Long Answer:

You fall trap to bad naming of functions.

`getDay()` [returns the **week**day](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) (values: 0 - 6)

`getDate()` [returns the **month**day](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp)